# Populate input using custom jquery dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I currently have the following code which works apart from I am unable to use jquery closest to populate the nearest input with the class selected.

Below is my current setup:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    enableSelectBoxes();
});

function enableSelectBoxes(){
    $('div.selectBox').each(function(){
    $(this).children('span.selected').html($(this).children('div.selectOptions').children('span.selectOption:first').html());
    $(this).attr('value',$(this).children('div.selectOptions').children('span.selectOption:first').attr('value'));

    $(this).children('span.selected,span.selectArrow').click(function(){
        if($(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').css('display') == 'none'){
            $(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').css('display','block');
        }else{
            $(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').css('display','none');
        }
    });

    $(this).find('span.selectOption').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().css('display','none');
        $(this).closest('div.selectBox').attr('value',$(this).attr('value'));
        $(this).parent().siblings('span.selected').html($(this).html());
        $(this).closest("input.selected").attr('value',$(this).attr('value'));
    });
});             
}//-->
```

Below is the line in the above code that I think should work:

```
$(this).closest("input.selected").attr('value',$(this).attr('value'));
```

HTML

```
<div class="selectBox" value="Other">
    <div class="form-group field-reviews-category_id required has-error">
        <input type="text" id="reviews-category_id" class="selected" name="Reviews[category_id]">
<div class="help-block">Category cannot be blank.</div>
</div>            <span class="selected">All Categories</span>
<span class="selectArrow">▼</span>
        <div class="selectOptions">
            <span class="selectOption" value="Other">All Categories</span>
            <span class="selectOption" value="10">Accessories</span><span class="selectOption" value="11">Hoodies</span><span class="selectOption" value="4">Jackets</span><span class="selectOption" value="5">Jewellery</span><span class="selectOption" value="3">Sweatshirts</span><span class="selectOption" value="8">T Shirts</span><span class="selectOption" value="9">Trainers</span>            </div>
    </div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4e2dtf2/)

Comment: Can you post a working jsfiddle?, or HTML at least.

Comment: @lmgonzalves added html to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happen here is that `input.selected` is no an "ancestor" of options, so you can't use `closest` for this. You should first back to `div.selectBox`, and then `find` the `input.selected`. That way:

```
$(this).closest('div.selectBox').find("input.selected").attr('value',$(this).attr('value'));
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/yw7hyeh5/

Learn more here: https://api.jquery.com/closest/